# Utterly senseless move sequence

Tags: master-games, reference-request

I noticed a game in my database with an utterly senseless move sequence , but approved from a database on the internet. I mean the game Viesturs Meijers - Roi Castineira Reinaldo , Pamplona 2008

Does someone have a source with a reasonable move-sequence ?

The game begins with

```
[fen ""]

1.c4 e5 2. b3 Nc6 3. Bb2 Nf6 4. e3 g6 5. Nf3 d6 6. d4 Bg7 7. dxe5 Ng4 8. Qd2 Nge5 9.Ne5 dxe5 10. Qd8 Nd8 11. Nc3 Ne6 12. Be2 Bf8 13. e4 Nc5 14. Rf1 Ne4 {from here on the moves make no sense)} 15. h4 h5
```

From 14...Ne4 the moves don't make sense.

Comment: I'll have a check of my databases see what i can find. I know some databases actually insert fake games so (for example not implying said organisations do this), chess.com rip the entire lichess database, a lichess employee can search a particular game and know that's what has occurred.

Comment: Many games are generated from board sensors. When these go haywire, you could end up with nonsensical moves and/or missing pieces and/or wrong pieces. Maybe this is such a case?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any info about Viesturs Meijers playing in Pamplona in 2008, like for example [here](https://www.mikelgurea.com/open-de-navidad25/).

That tournament was won by Reinaldo Roi Castineira though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this game was recorded wrongly. Just because a game appears on a database it doesn't mean it's been "verified" by anyone.

If this game was stored automatically from a chess set with sensors, then there was probably some sort of malfunction going on. I doubt a game that looks this stupid could have been inserted manually.

Answer (score 0):

I located the game in my personal reference database, Chessbases Mega Databases as well as 3 online databases.

In all databases the game presented as follows;

```
[Event "Pamplona-A 18th"]
[Site "Pamplona"]
[Date "2008.??."]
[Round "4"]
[White "Meijers, Viesturs"]
[Black "Reinaldo Castineira, Roi"]
[Result "0-1"]
[BlackElo "2516"]
[Classes "0"]
[ECO "A01"]
[TimeControl ""]
[WhiteElo "2514"]
[FEN ""]

1. c4 e5 2. b3 Nc6 3. Bb2 Nf6 4. e3 g6 5. Nf3 d6 6. d4 Bg7 7. dxe5 Ng4 8.Qd2= Ngxe5 9. Nxe5 dxe5 10. Qxd8+ Nxd8 11. Nc3 Ne6 12. Be2 Bf8 13. e4 Nc5 14. Rf1= Nxe4 15. h4 h5 16. Bg4 Nxc3 17. b4 b6 18. Bf3 c5 19. bxc5 bxc5 20. a4 0-1
```

I tend to agree that this isn't exactly the highest level of play.
Just through a quick read through of the positions I count no less than 4 blunders , and yes they all kick off after *14. Ne4*

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand master level play, but I'd say these moves don't make sense as shown either.  They're certainly all legal moves, but...

Comment: @Edward yes it should be corrected thank-you. 

Yeah definitely all legal moves. Definitely not good moves following ~Bg4. I count at least 4 blunders and no doubt the eval bar is going to be swinging all over the place.

Comment: Quick Summary. If i was a youtuber i would be going "Looking at the way they are hanging pieces boss i'd say 700s or absolutely inebriated GM's"